# Можно ли внутри одной функции def использовать ещё одну функцию def?

Tags: python, функции

Когда пытаюсь создать функцию def внутри другой функции def вторая функция (get_treaty2) подсвечивается серым и не читается.

```
def get_fin(message):
if message.text == 'Нет, больше нету':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, name + ', добрый день! \nСпасибо за продуктивную встречу, подведу наши договоренности:\n' + treaty +
                         '\nСроки договоренности: ' + que + '\nХорошего дня!')       #Вывод на экран

elif message.text == 'Да, есть ещё одна':
    def get_treaty2(message):
        global treaty2
        treaty2 = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'О чем вы договорились на встрече?', reply_markup=markup)  # Третий вопрос
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_date)
```

Comment: Создать-то можно, но если вы её нигде не будете использовать, то в этом нет никакого смысла

Answer (score 1):

Функция *get_treaty2* загорается серым потому, что вы ее нигде не используете. Например, PyCharm таким образом вам показывает, что этот код нигде не используется и наверное его стоит удалить\закомментировать. Если же вы поставите вызов этой фунции или напишите что-то такое, то все будет как обычно:

```
elif message.text == 'Да, есть ещё одна':
    def get_treaty2(message):
        global treaty2
        treaty2 = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'О чем вы договорились на встрече?', reply_markup=markup)  # Третий вопрос
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_date)

    get_treaty2(message)
```